# Can I prompt for user input after reading piped input on STDIN in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line, stdin

I'm trying to write a perl script that reads piped data, then prompts the user for input based on that data. The following script, `prompt_for_action`, is what I am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @hosts = ();
while (<>) {
    my $host = $_;
    $host =~ s/\n//; # strip newlines
    push(@hosts, $host);
}

for my $host (@hosts) {
    print "Do you want to do x with $host ? y/n: ";
    chomp(my $answer = <>);
    print "You said `$answer`.\n";
}
```

but when I run it there is no waiting for user input, it just blows through without waiting for me to type:

```
$ echo "test1.example.com
> test2.example.com" | ./prompt_for_action
Do you want to do x with test1.example.com ? y/n: You said ``.
Do you want to do x with test2.example.com ? y/n: You said ``.
```

If I don't read my data from STDIN...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @hosts = ('test1.example.com', 'test12.example.com');

for my $host (@hosts) {
    print "Do you want to do x with $host ? y/n: ";
    chomp(my $answer = <>);
    print "You said `$answer`.\n";
}
```

then script works fine:

```
$ ./prompt_for_action 
Do you want to do x with test1.example.com ? y/n: y
You said `y`.
Do you want to do x with test12.example.com ? y/n: n
You said `n`.
```

Is piping to STDIN and then prompting for user input possible? If so how?

Comment: It's incredible how good Perl is on breaking syntax highlighting systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Unix-y systems, you can open the `/dev/tty` pseudo-file for reading.

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    print "from STDIN: $_";
}
close STDIN;

# oops, need to read something from the console now
open TTY, '<', '/dev/tty';
print "Enter your age: ";
chomp($age = <TTY>);
close TTY;
print "You look good for $age years old.\n";
```

Comment: i was able to just close STDIN, then: open STDIN, "<", "/dev/tty", is there a reason you should not do this? It didnt seem to have any side effects as far as I could tell. Obviously doing this kind of 'bravery' programming is not advisable for large programs but small tools should be okay right?

Answer (score 1):

As for non-Unix-y systems you can use the [findConsole](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine#findConsole) from [Term::ReadLine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine), and then use its output like in [mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485201/5420570), e.g. instead of `/dev/tty` put in the output of `findConsole` first element.

Example on Windows:

```
use Term::ReadLine;
while (<STDIN>) {
    print "from STDIN: $_";
}
close STDIN;

# oops, need to read something from the console now
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('term');
my @_IO = $term->findConsole();
my $_IN = $_IO[0];
print "INPUT is: $_IN\n";
open TTY, '<', $_IN;
print "Enter your age: ";
chomp($age = <TTY>);
close TTY;
print "You look good for $age years old.\n";
```

outputs:

```
echo SOME | perl tty.pl
from STDIN: SOME
INPUT is: CONIN$
Enter your age: 12 # you can now enter here!
You look good for 12 years old.
```

Answer (score -2):

Once you pipe something through STDIN, your former STDIN (keyboard input) is being replaced by the pipe. So I don't think this is possible.