# How to read password line after pipe input to Perl script

Tags: perl, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to read `STDIN` and then get user input line without displaying it in terminal.

The `Term::ReadKey`'s solution with `ReadMode('noecho')` will not work because it uses `<STDIN>` and if it is not empty it immediately takes(that what is supposed to be file, e.g. piped data) as *input* and not actually works:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $_stdin = <STDIN>;
print "Enter your password:\n";
ReadMode('noecho');
my $_pass = ReadLine(0); # This one uses <STDIN>!
ReadMode(0);
print "STDIN:\n$_stdin\nPassword:\n$_pass\n";
```

output:

```
$ echo "some data" | perl term-readkey.pl
Enter your password:
Use of uninitialized value $_pass in concatenation (.) or string at term-readkey.pl line 10, <STDIN> line 1. 
STDIN:
some data

Password:
```

The only solution that I come with is to use `Term::ReadLine` which seems not using `<STDIN>` as `Term::ReadKey`, but the problem is that output of the `$_term->readline()` is visible:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $_stdin = <STDIN>;
my $_term = Term::ReadLine->new('term');
my $_pass = $_term->readline("Enter your password:\n");
print "STDIN:\n$_stdin\nPassword:\n$_pass\n";
```

output:

```
$ echo "some data" | perl term-readkey.pl
Enter your password:
25 # actually entered it, and its visible...
STDIN:
some data

Password:
25
```

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484431/can-i-prompt-for-user-input-after-reading-piped-input-on-stdin-in-perl), but the answer is working only on Unix'y systems and input is visible...

Comment: Note that ReadLine() is documented not to work on Windows (but you can just do `<STDIN>` instead). Is there a specific non-Unixy architecture you're looking to run this on?

Comment: you can try to combine device names returned by `Term::ReadLine` `findConsole` https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine#findConsole with the solution for Unix'y systems

Comment: @Ujin Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @Ujin But then again it is **visible**...

Comment: Ah found it, just use the `ReadMode('noecho', TTY)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found solution, which was quite simple:

Using the `Term::ReadKey`'s ReadMode with `Term::ReadLine`'s term's `IN`, example:

```
use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $_stdin = <STDIN>;
my $_term = Term::ReadLine->new('term');
ReadMode('noecho', $_term->IN);
my $_pass = $_term->readline("Enter your password:\n");
ReadMode(0, $_term->IN);
print "STDIN:\n$_stdin\nPassword:\n$_pass\n";
```

or(thanks to [Ujin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9602863/ujin))

```
use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $_stdin = <STDIN>;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('term');
my @_IO = $term->findConsole();
my $_IN = $_IO[0];
print "INPUT is: $_IN\n";
open TTY, '<', $_IN;
print "Enter your password:\n";
ReadMode('noecho', TTY);
my $_pass = <TTY>;
ReadMode(0, TTY);
close TTY;
print "STDIN:\n$_stdin\nPassword:\n$_pass\n";
```

outputs:

```
Enter your password:
     # here enter hiddenly
STDIN:
stdin input

Password:
paws
```