# How can I clear EOF on stdin ($*IN) after gettig it with get / prompt in Raku?

Tags: get, stdin, prompt, eof, raku

In my program, I'd like to read a line from `$*IN` in a loop, and for this I can use either `get` or `prompt`; however, I noticed that if I end my input immediately with EOF (e.g., with Ctrl-D in Linux / MacOS) then any subsequent uses of `get` or `prompt` for reading another line from `$*IN` will cause it to return `Nil`, meaning it still gets EOF from `$*IN`.

Example:

```
dd get;
dd get;
```

with an immediate EOF (ctrl-d), the program ends and outputs two `Nil`'s.

This problem doesn't happen if something is entered other than just a EOF.

Curiously, this problem also doesn't happen with `slurp`. I.e.,

```
dd slurp;
dd slurp;
```

After the first ctrl-d, `""` is printed by the first `dd` and then it waits for input due to the second `slurp`.

I think this is also them same problem with - https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4196

Comment: Isn't the desired/preferred behavior? Otherwise a 'transmission' (read: maliciously-crafted message) could tie up a machine with minimal effort.

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4336)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485201/2173773) Perl 5 answer, you can reopen STDIN after receiving an EOF by opening `/dev/tty`:

```
use v6;
print "Input line: ";
my $line = get;
if ($line === Any) {
    say "got EOF..";
    say "Reopening STDIN..";
    my $fh = open "/dev/tty", :r, chomp => $*IN.chomp, nl-in => $*IN.nl-in,
        encoding => $*IN.encoding;
    print "Enter new line: ";
    my $line = $fh.get();
    say "Got line: {$line}";
}
else {
    say "Not EOF, got line: {$line}";
}
```

the above works, but I am not sure how to reassign the reopened STDIN handle to `$*IN`..

I tried the following:

```
$*IN = IO::Handle.new(path => IO::Path.new("/dev/tty"), :r,
                        chomp => $*IN.chomp, nl-in => $*IN.nl-in,
                        encoding => $*IN.encoding);
```

but it did not reopen `$*IN`..

**Edit**

I also tried:

```
print "Input line: ";
my $line = get;
if ($line === Any) {
    say "got EOF..";
    say "Reopening STDIN..";
    $*IN.close;
    $*IN = open "/dev/tty", :r, chomp => $*IN.chomp, nl-in => $*IN.nl-in,
        encoding => $*IN.encoding;
    my $line = get;
    say "Got line: {$line}";
}
else {
    say "Not EOF, got line: {$line}";
}
```

but it did not work:

```
Input line: got EOF..
Reopening STDIN..
Cannot do 'get' on a handle in binary mode
  in block <unit> at ./11.raku line 12
```

**Edit 2**

I think I found the problem, in the above script you have to use `my $line = $*IN.get` instead of `my $line = get` (I am not sure why, looks like it could be a bug)

Comment: Thanks for trying. This is definitely a bug of Rakudo.

Comment: Assigning a handle to `$*IN` won't automatically open it for you. Open the handle, or do e.g. `$*IN = $fh`

Comment: @ugexe Unfortunately that does not work either. Assigning `$*IN = $fh` makes `get()` throw `Cannot do 'get' on a handle in binary mode` even if its `encoding` parameter shows `utf8`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/TxQ881Kx) is a link to the code I used.

Comment: For me `$*IN = $fh` works on your example until I do a second cntrl+d

Comment: @ugexe *"For me $*IN = $fh works on your example until I do a second cntrl+d"* Strange, [here](https://pastebin.com/FXTziZgQ) is the output I get (running [this](https://pastebin.com/TxQ881Kx) script). The only input I give is CTRL-D on the first prompt.